# Cura how to fix "on air support"

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures

I'm trying to generate G-code for handle in Cura.

Unfortunately Cura generates wrong supports - first layer of support has now background in starts in the air (see attached files)

So how to fix it? Is there any way (configuration etc.) to prevent such kind of supports?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Cura profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v0fryn33c3ap4v/cura_settings.curaprofile?dl=1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Andrew, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

Comment: I think your question already has [an answer](/a/11721) on question: "[Cura is printing support on nothing?](/q/11721)". It could be related to the slice options, if you could post those related to support settings it might be helpful for your question.

Comment: I've just uploaded, check it out, please

Comment: Please read the answer in the linked question, this exactly explains your problem. You have a 2 layer Z gap defined (assuming you are printing 0.12 mm layers). How many layers are "air"? You can enable "Touching Buildplate" for the "Suppor Placement" option with tree support.

Comment: What exactly shall I do? Current value of "Support z Distance" is 0.24 (Calculated automatically). I've changed it do 0,12 and 0, same issue. Enabling of touching build-plate option removes support inside the hole. I've decided to test "touching build-plate" with tee-support test feature. I'll share with result later.

Comment: OP has commented that he tried the suggestions in the linked comment already.

Comment: Is "XY overrides Z" perhaps your problem?

Comment: Well, enabling of "touching build-plate" with tee-support worked. Thanks for advice